# what does it mean ? openldap: TLS: no unlocked certificate for certificate '<some certificate subject>'

Tags: centos, openldap, nss, slapd

just spent a lot of time with centos 6.7 and openldap.
it was configured with simple certificates and a root-ca in nice little pem files, but after an upgrade from centos 6.4, connecting to the slapd with SSL failed.

finally i saw this:  moznss error -12268 and read here: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html and thought about it and indeed, i could find a configuration directive which disabled sslv3 and so apparently somehow because of that 'it' ran out of ciphers or something. i gotta look into it some more. maybe someone has a recommended TLSCipherSuite  directive or can confirm the centos defaults are good.

anyway...it still says this warning, as mentioned above, in the title:
TLS: no unlocked certificate for certificate ''

can someone explain it ?
i googled it and can't find context or a definition.
it says TLS, but is it from mozilla nss certificate database ?

slapd says this when i connect to it via openssl s_client on port 636:

```
slapd -d stats  -h 'ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:/// '  -u ldap
[...]
TLS: certificate 'mycertificate'      successfully loaded from moznss database.
TLS: no unlocked certificate for certificate 'OU=XXXX,O=YYY,C=ZZZ,ST=Wien,CN=somedomainname'.
560d66c7 conn=1001 fd=31 TLS established tls_ssf=256 ssf=256
```

(i edited the names out up there, the OU=XXX stuff is the subject of 'mycertificate')

i have a working ssl connection, but i just want to know what an unlocked certificate is in this context, and also why it says that.

any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this message in the sourcecode 
openldap-2.4.39/libraries/libldap/tls_m.c
The comment says "prefer unlocked key, then key from opened certdb, then any other"

My guess is that the routine is capable of unlocking a key and caching the answer. It seems to be a warning message, though, not an error.